# Git hook for serialVersionUID regeneration

Tags: java, serialization, githooks

Are there any ready-made git hooks for the automatic regeneration of serialVersionUID in Java project?

For example this hook can find changes between commits and regeneration serialVersionUID if class changed.

Comment: You *don't want* to automatically regenerate `serialVersionUIDs`, ever. You want them to remain the same. The notion that they should change when the class changes is baseless and dangerous.

Comment: Really? I thought that UID must be changed. Thanks! I will read documentations.

Comment: No. It is an urban myth. It is exactly what you *dont* want to do. Otherwise you introduce incompatibilities that you don't need.